Initial Object in Wedge Category
In Peter Smith's Introducing Category Theory, he defined a wedge category in some category $\mathsf{C}$ over objects $X, Y$ as consisting of triples $(S,f,g)$ as objects and morphisms $S \to S'$ as morphisms. By definition, the product of $X$ and $Y$ is the terminal object of this category. But does the initial object ever exist, and if so is it at all meaningful at all?

Please make your question self-contained by writing out the types of $S$, $f$, and $g$.

See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/444152/initial-cones-terminal-cocones

The wedge category $\mathsf{C}/XY$ Smith is describing has, for objects, dependent tuples $(S : \mathsf{C}, f_1 : S \to X, f_2 : S \to Y)$, and, for morphisms $(S, f_1, f_2) \to (S', f_1', f_2')$, morphisms $g : S \to S'$ making the obvious diagram commute, i.e. such that $f_1' \circ g = f_1$ and $f_2' \circ g = f_2$. This is also known as the category of cones over the diagram $(X, Y) : 2 \to \mathsf{C}$, and a terminal object in this category is a product $X \times Y$.
On the other hand, if $\mathsf{C}$ has an initial object $0$ then $(0, !, !)$ is an initial object in $\mathsf{C}/XY$. It may also be the case that $\mathsf{C}/XY$ has an initial object but $\mathsf{C}$ doesn't; this is most apparent if you think about posets, because then an initial object in $\mathsf{C}$ is a least element, while an initial object in $\mathsf{C}/XY$ is a minimal element of the subset of lower bounds of $X$ and $Y$.
This is a slight generalisation of the way colimits are computed in slice categories: see nLab or 1Lab.
